# SSL on Azure web app shows differently in browser vs. server

Tags: azure, ssl, openssl

I have a web app set up on Azure with a custom subdomain assigned and a standard (single-domain) SSL assigned to that subdomain.

When I visit the app through the browser, the SSL I uploaded shows up fine. This works on all browsers.

However, when I run the following:

```
openssl s_client -connect subdomain.mywebsite.com:443
```

I get the *.azurewebsites.net certificate in the response. The certificate I uploaded is nowhere to be found.

Why is this? How do I get the custom certificate to be pulled up on a server request instead of the wildcard azurewebsites one?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: You should also provide real information, and not fake information, like `mywebsite.com` (that's actually someone's real domain). If you provided real information, then folks like me might be inclined to provide a real answer as a comment (site rules don't allow us to provide answers to off-topic questions).

Comment: Understood. I was led to it through a programming issue as another server's script was trying to match the certificate on the domain name. As I found out, it has to do with the configuration in a shared environment like Azure Web Apps (the server will return a general, self-signed certificate, not a domain-specific certificate). So the question is resolved.